# Why is semicolon instead of colon used in the given sentence?

Tags: semicolons, colons

He nearly answered ***;*** "You can go to blazes for all I care."

Comment: Where is this sentence presented?

I don't agree with the use of a semicolon either, but don't see why a regular comma wouldn't just suffice (instead of a colon).

Comment: I have found many sources of the book online, and they have used colons, not semi colons. 

See here: http://gutenberg.net.au/ebooks05/0500111h.html

Comment: This sentence is taken from famous James Hilton's novel "Mr. Chips" so how does it wrong?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about a typo or scanning error.

Comment: O.K @ Inazuma  you are right as this is only a typing error. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It shouldn't. Before a quotation, you can use a comma if it is short enough, or a colon otherwise. There isn't a case where you would use a semicolon.